# Display a sequence of images like a video?

Tags: ios, animation, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm experimenting with image processing algorithms on iOS. I've got an asset catalog with images `test_frame1` ... `test_frame100` (and the like) on which I do some processing.

Among other things I need to display the images sequentially as if they were frames of a video.

The first thing that came to my mind is sequentially change the image of a `UIImage` after some milliseconds delay. I'm doing this asynchronously. Here's the code:

```
    let imageShowQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.grigoryptashko.ImageShowQueue",
        DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    let frameShowDelay = Int64(0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) // show images with 200 ms delay, but it doesn't actually work this way
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        var dTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, frameShowDelay)
        for i in 1...1000 {
            dispatch_after(dTime, self.imageShowQueue) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    NSLog("test_frame\((i % 100) + 1)")
                    self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "test_frame\((i % 100) + 1)")
                    self.imgView.setNeedsDisplay()
                }
            }

            dTime = dispatch_time(dTime, frameShowDelay)
        }
    }
```

It actually works but the FPS quickly becomes too low, like 1 FPS or even slower. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Maybe, there is some way that I don't know about. For instance, recently I've learned about `Accelerate` framework and `Apple Metal`. Ant other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want an image based animation. Here is what you would do:

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
self.<name of the UIImageView you want to animate>.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"],nil];
                      /* Do this until you have all the images in the array */
self.<name of the UIImageView you want to animate>.animationDuration = 1.0f;
self.<name of the UIImageView you want to animate>.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

Then you use `[<name of the UIImageView you want to animate> startAnimating];` were you want the animation to start. The numbers for `animationDuration` and `animationRepeatCount` can be changed to what value you want them to be. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image) is the link the the Apple Docs.

For Swift development:

```
<name of the UIImageView you want to animate>.animationImages = [
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!,
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!,
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!,
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!,
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!,
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!,
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!,
                                         UIImage(named: "Image Name")!
                                       ]
                          /* Do this until you have all the images in the array */
<name of the UIImageView you want to animate>.animationDuration = 1.0
<name of the UIImageView you want to animate>.animationRepeatCount = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more direct way of doing this by using `animatedImageNamed:` on `UIImage`. Check this out:

```
UIImage *animatingImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"test_frame_" duration:1.0];
UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:animatingImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, change the images in array and compile the project, in this part set de time interval

```
animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;
```

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/